# How to bundle specific version of webrowser control?

Tags: .net, browser, webbrowser-control

I'm wondering if there is a way to bundle specific IE version dlls with my application so I get same results when hosting webrowser control.

For examsple I'd like to have a way to bundle IE8 webrowser control, it will help me to avoid problems on computers where user is not using IE, and he hasn't upgraded it since IE6 or IE7, and because of that I need to invest much more effort to make sure, html/scripts/css I write in my webrowser control are working ok on all IE versions.

From what I know, webrowser control consists of mshtml.dll and shdocw.dll, but I don't know how to bind to them without conflicting with what is already installed on system.

If not, I guess I'll go with WebKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not as easy as that. The IE browser is so tightly tied into the system that there can only be one version of it installed.

To be able to use different versions of the dll:s, you would have to intercept the system itself when it's loading the dll:s. There are some applications that does this so that you can run several versions of IE simultaneously, but this only works partially, there are still some features in the browser that doesn't work properly.

Comment: Correct. Redistribution of these DLLs is not supported or (legally) permitted.

Comment: I'll go with an alternative I guess, WebKit or Firefox. From experience it's a hell supporting all version of IE, and after each fix running everything on IE6 through IE10. It would be much helpful if MS will make it possible to take with you whatever IE engine you want with you application.